# UIViewController subclass strategy

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uikit

Let's say I have a tabbed application in which each tab displays different categories of similar data (eg. Tab1: "Cat Pictures", Tab2: "Dog Pictures", Tab3: "Horse Pictures", etc...).

The view controllers for each tab present data identically. The only differences are the title property of the vc and the parameters of the method that fetches the data. So what are the pros and cons of the following options:

- Create one ViewController master with the (limited) branching
     logic for each category.
- Create a ViewController
     superclass and several subclasses for the different category types.

**EDIT**

So to clarify "the parameters of the method that fetches the data": the fetch method could look like:

```
-(void)fetchDataForType:(NSString*)type {
       if ([type isEqual:@"cat"])
           // fetch cat pics
       if ([type isEqual:@"dog"])
           // fetch dog pics
       ...
 }
```

Comment: Please clarify "and the parameters of the method that fetches the data".  What are these differences?

Answer (score 1):

In your case I wouldn't even subclass. Create one class with properties you would change and instantiate with different properties values.

Rough example:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *title;
- (void)getJSONWithParams:(NSDictionary *)params;
@end
```

Instances:

```
ViewController *controller1 = [[ViewController alloc] init];
controller1.title = @"First";
NSDictionary *params1 = @{@"url":@"http://graph.facebook.com", @"query":@"q=somethingInFacebook"};
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller1];
[controller1 getJSONWithParams:params1];

ViewController *controller2 = [[ViewController alloc] init];
controller2.title = @"Second";
NSDictionary *params2 = @{@"url":@"http://api.twitter,com", @"query":@"q=somethingInTwitter"};
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller2];
[controller2 getJSONWithParams:params2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Short term project:

- I would keep one `UIViewController` where the data source would change (in this case the kind of pictures)

Long term project:

- I would probably sub-class, because you might need to add smaller differences after and creating the sub-classes now will save you some time later. Even in a short term project, you can use this approach. Since the data source is the only that changes, the sub-classes would be mostly empty.

Answer (score 0):

Create `AbstractViewController` holds all common Information and has all methods. Create several `ViewControllers` as you wish and they inherit from the `super` and override functions with their behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a single UIViewController subclass can provide everything you require.  You just need to provide the *differences* required to support each different type of picture.  Let's assume those differences are just the description and type of picture it shows:

MyViewController.h:

```
@MyViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *description;
@property (strong, nomatomic) NSString *type;

// Designated initializer
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName
               bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle
          description:(NSString *)description
                 type:(NSString *)type;

@end
```

MyViewController.m:

```
@implementation MyViewController

 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName
                bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle
           description:(NSString *)description
                  type:(NSString *)type
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundle];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        self.description = description;
        self.type = type;
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSArray *)fetchPics
{
    NSMutableArray *pics = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.somewhere.com/fetchPics?type=%@", self.type]];
    ...

    return pics;
}

@end
```

And it should then just be a case of creating the view controllers whereever necessary:

```
MyViewController *catVC = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"Something" bundle:nil description:@"Cats" type:@"cat"];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't subclass at all.  You create one view controller with properties that you can change at set up, and create an instance per tab.  There is nothing stopping you create multiple instances of a view controller.  You don't need one view controller for one view hierarchy.